# Slow website from one connection

Tags: isp, networking

One of the websites is very slow on response from one particular connection.
The trace route seems to be alright (total is ~110ms) but all pages of the site take much time to load.

It works properly from few other connections.

What can be causing this issue? ISP? What should I ask them?

Thanks and Happy New Year everyone :)

Comment: Need a little bit more information. Where else are you trying this from? Other internet connections? Different computers on the same connection? etc.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response - different computers, different networks. Only from one connection the site works slow (all computers) - from other connections it works fast.

Comment: MTU on that connection is maybe different, and causes fragmentation and/or dropped packets. Or the connection itself is not as big (not same bandwidth) as the faster one??

Comment: Do you host the web site? Do you have experience with wireshark?

Comment: @OlivierDulac - it's the other way around - the site works slow on faster connection. regarding the host - yes, I'm checking out Wireshark now. Thank you both for answers